# imap_open very long delay

Tags: php, imap

We use the following code to connect to IMAP via SSL:

```
imap_timeout(IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT, 5);
imap_timeout(IMAP_READTIMEOUT, 5);
imap_timeout(IMAP_WRITETIMEOUT, 5);
imap_timeout(IMAP_CLOSETIMEOUT, 5);

$connection = null;
try {
    $connection = imap_open('{'.$host.':'.$port.'/service='.$service.$crypt.'/novalidate-cert}', $user, $pass, OP_SILENT, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Errors logged in a summary below
}
```

This works often without any issue. However, sometimes it hangs on imap_open for more than 800s. The error it returns is:

```
TLS\/SSL failure for imap.xxx.net: SSL negotiation failed
```

How can I make sure imap_open does not wait so long?

Comment: You can't set the timeout for SSL connections. This bug has been open [since 2012](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61846). Some people have reported success using `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5);` but others have reported that this didn't help, so YMMV (which is why I didn't post this as an answer).

Comment: Ok, does set_time_limit(x) o rini_set('max_execution_time', x) work?

Comment: Not to abort the imap connection, but it could work to kill your whole script