# imap_open() function getting stuck on unreachable ip address using php-7.4

Tags: php, user-interface, php-7.4, imap-open

Below is my code and i m using PHP-7.4.33

```
$mbox = imap_open ("{10.10.10.1:995/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "user_id", "password",0,0);
print_r($mbox, true)
```

now wen hit on this code its getting stuck and not returning anything. what can i do in such cases ?
how to set timeout ?
kindly guide me further...

I have tried below

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 2);
imap_timeout(IMAP_READTIMEOUT,2);

but its not working.

Comment: When the IP address is not reachable to begin with, then you won't be doing any reading - so why are you setting IMAP_READTIMEOUT, and not IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT?

Comment: the host/ip is dynamic, u can say an input by user. so user can input an unreachable host also. but my imap_open stuck over there. I need something that can say the ip/host is not reachable.

it will be also helpful to me wen an active host not replying.

Comment: So did you try IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT, or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407026/imap-open-very-long-delay#comment97535758_55407026 suggests that timeouts might not work for SSL connections, due to a still unfixed bug.

Comment: Can I have any work around which can identify a never return connection.

Comment: Maybe try and see if you can establish a connection using `fsockopen` first, or something like that.

Comment: ok, let me check, thanks for all the guidance.